# AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Anonymous Type to Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

This is my Acquirer Model class where I am managing the Request Properties:

```
public class Acquirer{
        public string MERCHANTNO {get;set;}
        public float TRANSACTIONAMOUNT{get;set;}
        public DateTime PROCESSDATE{get;set;}
              
        public Acquirer(){}

        public Acquirer(float TRANSACTIONAMOUNT,DateTime PROCESSDATE,string MERCHANTNO){
                     this.TRANSACTIONAMOUNT=TRANSACTIONAMOUNT;
                     this.PROCESSDATE=PROCESSDATE;       
                     this.MERCHANTNO=MERCHANTNO;
        }
}
```

This is my Response Class AcquirerDTO.cs where I am getting all the response:

```
public class AcquirerDTO{
    public string MERCHANTNO {get;set;}
    public float TRANSACTIONAMOUNT{get;set;}
    public DateTime PROCESSDATE{get;set;}
}
```

My AutoMapperClass, AutoMapper.cs:

```
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Acquirer, AcquirerDTO>(); 
    }
}
```

This is where the mapping is done i am getting this:

> error Mapping types:
> <>f__AnonymousType2`2[] -> AcquirerDTO

```
    var datasend = (from h in searchResponse.Hits
                                select new { 
                                MerchantNo=h.Source.MERCHANTNO,
                                ProcessDate=h.Source.PROCESSDATE,
                                TransactionAmount=h.Source.TRANSACTIONAMOUNT
                                }
                              ).ToArray();

                var datasendd = datasend
               .GroupBy(s => new { s.MerchantNo, s.ProcessDate })
               .Select(g =>
                  new
                  {
                      PROCESSDATE = g.Key.ProcessDate,
                      TransactionAmountSum = g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount)
                  }).ToArray();


                //var AcquirerDTO = _mapper.Map<Acquirer, List<AcquirerDTO>>(datasendd);
                var AcquirerDTO = _mapper.Map<AcquirerDTO>(datasendd);
                //var AcquirerDTO = _mapper.Map<AcquirerDTO>(datasendd);
```

Comment: Two things: frist - you are mapping array of objects to single object `AcquirerDTO`, what you probably meant is to map to a list of `AcquirerDTO` since source object is a collection too. Second - AutoMapper doesn't know how to map from anonymous object. You defined a map from `Acquirer` to `AcquirerDTO`, so try to pass `Acquirer` instead of anonymous object when mapping to `AcquirerDTO`. Just modify your select in query to create `Acquirer`. Still I don't understand the `GroupBy()` part of your code.

Comment: The best option is just to read the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#lists-and-arrays) about mapping from and to collections. The `Select()` should be in your first query, since what I can see there you already create an object with properties matching those of `Acquirer`. I hardly can help you more since I'm limited here by lack of information of your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done by like this

```
var datasendd = datasend
           .GroupBy(s => new { s.MerchantNo, s.ProcessDate })
           .Select(g =>
              new Acquirer
              {
                  PROCESSDATE = g.Key.ProcessDate,
                  TransactionAmountSum = g.Sum(x => x.TransactionAmount)
              }).ToArray();


            List<AcquirerDTO> listDest = _mapper.Map<Acquirer[], List<AcquirerDTO>>(datasendd);
```